# Passing argument to setTimeout in a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, arguments, settimeout

I'm trying to learn how to pass an argument to setTimeout in a javacript for loop.  Here is the example code.  As it is currently written, setTimeout is passed the same exact i each time, not reflecting the different i's that are actually in the array.

```
var a=100;
for (i in array)
{   
    setTimeout("do_stuff(i, a)"), 2000);    
}
```

(I've seen somewhat similar questions and answers here, but the code examples are much more complicated.  Answering this most basic example could much help others with the same problem. Thanks!!!)

Comment: note that `for(x in y)` does not do what you expect it to, and doesn't work for iterating arrays

Comment: @then: It seems that you lost your account access and made a new one - flag this for a moderator to merge your accounts. Then you can accept the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

To use a string *(which you shouldn't do)*, you 'd need to do this:

```
var a=100;
for (i in array)
{   
    setTimeout("do_stuff(" + i + ", a)"), 2000);    
}
```

A better answer would be to scope the `i` variable in a new function invocation, which returns an anonymous function to give to `setTimeout()`.

```
function do_stuff( i, a ) {
    return function() {
        // do something with i and a
    }
}

var a=100;
for (i in array)
{   
    setTimeout(do_stuff( i , a ), 2000);    
}
```

Now `do_stuff()` *returns* a function that has a scoped reference to a new `i` and `a` variable. Because each call to `do_stuff` will have its own scope, the function you return will reference the correct values.

---

**EDIT:** *Off topic, but if `array` is actually an `Array`, then you really shouldn't use `for-in` because that's meant for **enumeration**. With an Array, you typically want **iteration** of numeric indices, and as such should use a standard `for` loop.*